Drifted Brownian Motion hits Two-Sided Barrier Almost Surely
Let $$X_t = X_ 0 + \int_0^t g(X_t)dt + B_t$$ e.g. $X_t$ satisfies the SDE:
$$
dX_t = g(X_t)dt + dB_t
$$
where $g$ is (say) globally Lipschitz and bounded (I only say this is so that the above SDE has a solution for every $T > 0$), and $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. Let $\tau$ be the first time the process hits a two - sided barrier:
$$
\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X_t =a \text{ or } X_t = b\}
$$
where $a < X_0 < b$. I know in the case when $g = 0$ (e.g. we have standard Brownian motion) that $\mathbb{P}(\tau = + \infty) =0$ (this is even true for a one-sided barrier, say by the LIL.
My question: is this true in the case of general drift $g$?
My attempt: We know that the result is true for standard brownian motion, so we look for a way to transform the process $X_t$ into one. This is furnished by the Girsanov theorem, which tells us for any $T > 0$ that:
$$
\int_0^t g(X_t)dt + B_t
$$
is a standard brownian motion on $[0,T]$ under measure $\mathbb{Q}_T$ where:
$$
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_T}{d\mathbb{P}} = \exp\left(-\int_0^Tg(X_t)dBt - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^Tg(X_t)^2dt\right)
$$
We know $\mathbb{P}(\tau = +\infty) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(\tau \geq n)$. So I am tempted to say:
$$
\mathbb{Q}_n(\tau \geq n) = \mathbb{P}(\tau \geq n)
$$
and somehow show that the limit on the LHS is zero. But in general, the dependence of $\mathbb{Q}_n$ on $n$ seems to mess this up. If we had that the stochastic exponential in the theorem above was uniformly integrable, then we would be done as we could use $\mathbb{Q}_n$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}_T$. But I don't think this is true without more assumptions on $g$ (e.g. square integrability) that I feel like shouldn't be necessary (of course I am happy to be corrected!)
In some sense - $g = 0$ should be the worst case, and drifts that "repel" the process away from a barrier should be excluded by a Lipschitz/Linear growth condition. But I can't really make this precise and it may well be incorrect.

The answer is no. In fact, for example, setting $a=0,b>0$ it has been shown that there exists a whole class of functions $\mathcal{H}$ such that if $h \in \mathcal{H}$ then there exists a solution to the SDE
$$dX_t=\frac{h'(X_t)}{h(X_t)}dt+dB_t,\,\,X_0=x\in (0,b)$$
such that $P^x(\tau=\infty)=1$. I refer OP to (one of) the references, Çetin-Hok (2024) Th. 2.6.
